# Replacing symbolic variables inside of a compile

Tags: replacement, evaluation, symbolic, compile

As the result of a symbolic integration, I have a very long array with symbolic variables `u[i]` which I would like to substitute for real number values. Moreover, I would like to do this using a compiled function for efficiency.

For simplicity say we have the array

```
aLong := {u[1]/u[2], u[1]*u[2]}
```

I want to compile a function whose job is to evaluate this expression.

However, if I try:

```
f=Compile[{{w,_Real,1}},aLong/.{u[1]->w[[1]],u[2]->w[[2]]}]
f[{1,2}]
```

it gives errors:

`CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression {0.5,2.} should be a machine-size real number.`

`CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.`

If instead I try Evaluate inside of the Compile, then I get the following error:

```
f = Compile[{{w, _Real, 1}}, Evaluate[aLong /. {u[1] -> w[[1]], u[2] -> w[[2]]}]];
f[{1, 1}]
```

`Part::partd: Part specification w[[1]] is longer than depth of object.`

`Part::partd: Part specification w[[2]] is longer than depth of object.`

Any suggestions that can help me fix this? (there must be something very basic I have not understood) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really an error, only a warning message, if `w` is atomic.  It's not an error in the sense that `w[[1]]` is the result of `Part` evaluating before `w` has a value and that this result is what is intended.  Nonetheless, the error message is irritating.

One way:

```
f = Block[{w}, (* in case w has a value *)
  Quiet[
   Compile[{{w, _Real, 1}}, 
    Evaluate[aLong /. {u[1] -> w[[1]], u[2] -> w[[2]]}]],
   Part::partd] (* turn off the specific message *)
   ];
f[{1, 1}]
(*  {1., 1.}  *)
```

An alternative that avoids "errors":

```
f = Block[{Compile, Part, w}, (* suspend evaluation until safe *)
   Compile[{{w, _Real, 1}}, 
    aLong /. {u[1] -> w[[1]], u[2] -> w[[2]]}]
   ];
f[{1, 1}]
(*  {1., 1.}  *)
```

*Update.* Third way (`Block[]` not needed):

```
f = Hold@Compile[{{w, _Real, 1}}, aLong] /.
     OwnValues@aLong /. 
    {u[1] :> w[[1]], u[2] :> w[[2]]} //
   ReleaseHold;
f[{1, 1}]
(*  {1., 1.}  *)
```

Comment: Ok, so let's see if I understood, the idea is: 
1. Use Hold to maintain the whole expression unevaluated.
2. Use Replace + HoldPattern to replace the string aLong for the vector
3. Use Replace together with :> to substitute the u[i] for w[[i]] without the warning appearing because of the hold on :>
4. Finally, release the hold.

This way of working with unevaluated expressions is new to me. Very useful though. Thank you!

Comment: @mmendez Yes (for the summary of the third alternative). The ability to generate code is a notable feature of Mma. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22code%20generation%22%20-%22C%22 or [tag:code-generation] for more. --  Here a shorter version: `f = Hold@Compile[{{w, _Real, 1}}, aLong] /. OwnValues@aLong /. u[i_] :> w[[i]] // ReleaseHold`

Answer (score 2):

This would fix the issue (it might not be the cleanest solution though)

```
aLong := {u[1]/u[2], u[1]*u[2]}
expr = aLong /. {u[1] -> w[[1]], u[2] -> w[[2]]} // Quiet;

f = Compile[{{w, _Real, 1}},
  Evaluate@expr
];

f[{1,2}]
>> {0.5, 2.}
```

Here `Quiet[]` prevents errors from `w[[1]]` being undefined yet

Comment: If I understand correctly you are only hiding the error messages. Right? Is this common practice in Mathematica? I was hoping for an approach that would not produce errors in the first place.

Comment: @mmendez I would not say it is common place to simply hide errors but in some cases it can be a good solution. Micheal produced a solution without errors but arguably it is more complicated